# Passing a block as keyword argument

Tags: ruby

Is it possible (if yes how) to pass a block as a keyword argument in a ruby method?

Basically, I'd like to do

```
pippo(even: {|n| n+1 }, odd: {|n| n-1})
```

Having the method defined as such

```
def pippo(even: , odd:)
  even? ? even.yield(self) : odd.yield(self)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `when` is a [keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. As you may imagine the sample code has just for demonstration and I'm not planning to create a `when` method.

Comment: 15 minutes from posting to selecting an answer! That's bad, not good (imo).  Not only may a lightning-fast selection discourage other answers, but it's a bit dismaying for those still working on answers (here at least two) to see the checkmark flash on so soon after the question has been posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to supply multiple blocks you need to pass them through as a Proc, or use the `lambda` construct to declare them:

```
when(
  even: -> (x) { x+1 },
  odd: -> (x) { x-1 }
)
```

You can also declare them using `proc { ... }` or `lambda { ... }` which is the old style declaration for same.

Comment: lambda is not equal to proc

Comment: There's important differences, but in this case they can both be supplied as arguments.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes, they can, but I suggest fixing the misleading wording. :)

Comment: Any reference to a Proc will do here. I'm *recommending* the `lambda` approach.

Comment: btw, why would one use `Proc.new { ... }` when there's `proc { ... }`? :)

Comment: Never had occasion to use the new notation for that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: A loooong time ago, `Kernel#proc` was an alias for `Kernel#lambda` and thus returned a lambda. It was then changed to basically do `def proc(&blk) Proc.new(&blk) end`. However, if you didn't know what Ruby version your code would be running on, you would have to avoid `Kernel#proc` because you couldn't know what it would do. Rubyists who learned Ruby before 2003 tend to avoid `Kernel#proc` for that reason, even though Ruby versions in which it returns a lambda have been retired long ago.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yes, but in 1.8 it does something different (returns a lambda instead of a plain `Proc`) than it does in 1.9+, so anybody who learned Ruby during the period where 1.8 and 1.9 were used in parallel tends to avoid it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: ah, thanks for this history lesson! I myself started with ruby in 2008. :)

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. Blocks aren't objects, you can't pass them as arguments, *except* as block arguments. They are a lightweight syntactic and semantic construct that is *only* allowed as a block argument to a message send. The light weight of blocks is predicated on the fact that there can be at most one block, and thus it doesn't need to be named and/or bound to a parameter.

What you *can* do, however, is pass multiple `Proc`s or lambdas. After all, `Proc`s and lambdas are objects like any other object, so you can pass them as arguments like any other object:

```
pippo(even: -> n { n+1 }, odd: -> n { n-1 })

def pippo(even: , odd:)
  if even? then even.(self) else odd.(self) end
end
```

Actually, this allows you to pass *any* object which responds to `call`, e.g. a `Method`:

```
pippo(even: 1.method(:+), odd: 1.method(:-))
```

Comment: `1.method(:succ)` is not equivalent to `-> (n) { n + 1 }`

Comment: Of course, stupid typo. I mixed up two different examples I was trying out.

Comment: A minor difference: one invokes `n + 1`, the other `1 + n`, but this example is obviously about integers, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Argh, you're right. `-` is not associative. It's still too early for me.